# Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/php-5.6/extensions/json.so'

Tags: php, codeigniter

after download `CodeIgniter` v3, Now I getting this error :

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Core Warning

Message: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/php-5.6/extensions/json.so' - /usr/local/php-5.6/extensions/json.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Filename: Unknown

Line Number: 0

Backtrace:
```

My address :

http://vitrinsaz1.ir/Mobile/Vitrinsaz/Pannel/index.php/welcome

Comment: Does `/usr/local/php-5.6/extensions/json.so` exist?

Comment: there is not this path in CodeIgniter

Comment: Nothing to do with CodeIgniter. It is a PHP configuration issue. Notice it is a PHP Startup error. Either you have the wrong version of json.so,  or the file does not exist (at least not in the path indicated).